# Orthogonalization of complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors: $ \vec{v}=[i,1],  \vec{u}=[1,-i]$ and I have to orthogonalize them, and I am doing it with the Gram-Schmidt process but it does not work because I do not get orthogonal vectors. Could someone tell me why? That is how I am calculating it:
$\vec{u} \circ \vec{v}= 2i \\ \vec{v} \circ \vec{v} = 2 \\ \vec{u} \prime= \vec{u}-\frac{\vec{u}\circ\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\circ\vec{v}}\vec{v}, \vec{u} \prime= [1,-i] - i[i,1]=[2,-2i]$

$\vec{u} \prime \circ \vec{v}  = -4i$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\vec{v} = i\cdot \vec{u}$. Your vectors aren't linearly independent. For the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, you need a set of linearly independent vectors.

Still, for linearly dependent vectors, you should get $\vec{u}' = 0$ as the result. You don't, because you should compute

$$\vec{u}' = \vec{u} - \frac{\vec{v}\circ\vec{u}}{\vec{v}\circ\vec{v}}\vec{v}$$

when your inner product is antilinear in the first argument. You have

$$(\vec{u} - c\vec{v})\circ \vec{v} = \vec{u}\circ\vec{v} - \overline{c}(\vec{v}\circ\vec{v}),$$

so you need

$$c = \overline{\frac{\vec{u}\circ\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\circ\vec{v}}} = \frac{\vec{v}\circ\vec{u}}{\vec{v}\circ\vec{v}}.$$

Comment: So I can't orthogonalize them?

Comment: No, orthogonality implies linear independence for non-zero vectors. So you can't get a non-zero orthogonal vector from linearly dependent vectors with the algorithm.

Comment: But see the update, @jaranna, there was more to it.

Comment: I do not where it came from: $(\vec{u} - c\vec{v})\circ \vec{v} = \vec{u}\circ\vec{v} - \overline{c}(\vec{v}\circ\vec{v})$ ? Could you elaborate on it a little more?

Comment: If the inner product is antilinear in the first argument, as it follows from $[1,-i]\circ[i,1] = 2i$, then you have $(c\cdot\vec{v})\circ \vec{v} = \overline{c}\cdot(\vec{v}\circ\vec{v})$. If the inner product were linear in the first and antilinear in the second argument, you'd have $\vec{u}\circ\vec{v} = -2i$. The formula $$\vec{u}' = \vec{u} - \frac{\vec{u}\circ\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\circ\vec{v}}\vec{v}$$ is for inner products that are linear in the first argument, for inner products that are linear in the second argument, you must take the inner product in the other order.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Thank you for that. You are the first source I've ever heard state this fact despite it being so important. It seems like every text out there goes with one convention or the other, but never mentions the differences between the two and how it affects the projection operation onto the basis vectors.